# Return Empty String Instead of Null

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0, mapster

I am using ef core and [mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster). I have some columns in my db that are nullable.

When I get them from the db, C# stores them as nulls(which makes sense). I want to return these fields are empty strings though when I send them back via my api.

```
public class CompanyDto
    {

        public string Website { get; set; }
    }


 public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; } = "";
    }

company.Adapt<CompanyDto>()
```

what is the best way to make it so Website in the CompanyDto is an empty string.

Comment: You can use Nullabl type for int to store null value

Comment: What about [custom mapping](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Custom-mapping) and then something like `src => src ?? string.Empty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic setter will do the job as well

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private string _website;
    public string Website 
    { 
        get { return _website; }
        set { _website = value ?? string.Empty; }
    };

    public Company ()
    {
        _website = string.empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not seem to work, I put a breakpoint and it was never triggered, so maybe it being bypassed somehow. I moved the check to the get method and that will work.

Comment: Seems like mapster simply skip property if original value is null. You can set default value in constructor.